# Sqoop command for import table

Tags: mysql, cassandra, datastax, sqoop, datastax-enterprise

I'm using dse 5.0.3 with have sqoop version 1.4.5.15.1 while im importing my data from mysql to cql  this error i get

```
./dse sqoop cql-import --table npa_nxx --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/npa_nxx_demo --username root --password 123
```

ERROR 13:20:53,886 Imported Failed: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory.

Please help me to solve it.!!

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to be exact about the problem but I'd suggest that you aren't including any cassandra parameters to the cql-import command is attempting to import to an hdfs directory that also isn't declared. Try including a cassandra-keyspace and cassandra-table on the command. Like:

```
./dse sqoop cql-import --table npa_nxx --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/npa_nxx_demo --username root --password 123 --cassandra-keyspace npa_nxx --cassandra-table npa_nxx_data
```

This assumes that the cassandra keyspace and table are correctly setup.

Since this import looks like it is from the dse sqoop demo I'd suggest following the README.txt more closely as it has the correct options for this import in it.

Comment: Again it same                                                                                     ./dse sqoop cql-import --table npa_nxx --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/npa_nxx_demo --username root --password 123 --cassandra-keyspace npa_nxx --cassandra-table npa_nxx_data
Hadoop functionality is deprecated and may be removed in a future release.
WARN  11:40:22,607 Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
ERROR 11:40:23,160 Imported Failed: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory